# Android AlertDialog Not Working

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How do I define "The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(XMLParser) is undefined" . I'm having error on my codes. Please teach me how to make it work . I'm trying to show an alert dialog box when exception has been caught in my app.

```
public class XMLParser {
private Context context;
// constructor


/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage( "Host not found" )
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Exit",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }

                            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();



            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
```

}

Logcat :

```
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:142)
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:359)
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     at com.example.androidhive.XMLParser.getDomElement(XMLParser.java:80)
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     at com.example.androidhive.CategoryList$loadlistView.doInBackground(CategoryList.java:112)
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     at com.example.androidhive.CategoryList$loadlistView.doInBackground(CategoryList.java:1)
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-26 22:37:34.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2221):     ... 4 more
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221): Activity com.example.androidhive.CategoryList has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41649130 that was originally added here
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.CategoryList has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41649130 that was originally added here
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:428)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at com.example.androidhive.CategoryList$loadlistView.onPreExecute(CategoryList.java:102)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at com.example.androidhive.CategoryList.checkInternetConnection(CategoryList.java:158)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at com.example.androidhive.CategoryList.onCreate(CategoryList.java:47)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
08-26 22:37:40.399: E/WindowManager(2221):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you are closing the application as soon as alert dialog is shown, remove all calls to   System.exit(0);

Comment: i removed it already. But i'm still having problems when the code passes through AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); it goes to threadpoolexecutor.class

Comment: but its not throwing any exceptions

Comment: isnt not throwing exceptions a good thing? Is it crashing? If so post the logcat output. Try to put logs rather than trying to debug.  Also if you are showing dialog in non-Ui thread , it will result in exception.

Comment: I think its because my progress dialog is still running and my new alert dialog box couldnt overwrite it.

Comment: Is there anyway to dismiss my progress dialog from another class?

Comment: yes, there are too many ways , you could use Handler and send a message to the activity to close Activity

Comment: could you please show an example. I can give you credit for that. thanks nandeesh.

Comment: i cant seem to find any, but you can search on the internet, but i think you will have to improvise from the normal samples related to handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the Constructor for AlertDialog.Builder is

```
AlertDialog.Builder(Context context)
```

**Constructor using a context for this builder and the AlertDialog it creates.**

and in your code `this` refers to your **XMLParser Class** not any Context

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Instead of passing `.this` pass the **Context of Calling Activity or Application.**

something like,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
```

Comment: I've edited my codes. But doesnt seems to work either. when the code passes through AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); it goes to threadpoolexecutor.class

Answer (score 0):

If you have the AlertDialog.Builder object, simply call show on that. The easiest example:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(someContext).setMessage("Some text").show();
```

You can also do this, after you set the buttons on it, etc...